# DISTINCT statement in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

How do you get DISTINCT to end only at 'serviceType'?  I've tried union and intersect to no avail.

```
$tsql = "SELECT DISTINCT serviceType, product, provider, rate, qty, updated FROM contracts WHERE client='{$_POST['client']}' ";
```

I need to see the latest updated serviceType record with the rest of the available information, but not every little change that I make.  However, I would like to keep the changes as an archive.

Comment: dont you just need to get * FROM contracts ORDER BY updated desc LIMIT 1?

Comment: @juju limit is not SQL Server. They want the latest row per servicetype as ordered by the updated column descending I believe. So dupe of many greatest n per group questions.

Comment: Yes that is what I need Martin.  I'll start working on a solution, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I was thinking, I have an ID as the identifier and primary key in this table, the highest # ID is created per new record.  Couldn't I just do something like:  WHERE client='{$_POST['client']}' AND ID of servicetype is highest?

Comment: sounds like it, MAX(ID)..?

Comment: Not working.  "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected".  I'll have to give another shot at it tomorrow with a fresh mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write  that query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT distinct  main.serviceType, b.product, b.provider, b.rate, b.qty, b.updated
FROM contracts  as main
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 
                    serviceType, product, provider, rate, qty, updated 
             FROM contracts as sub
             where main.serviceType = sub.serviceType
             Order by updated  desc
             ) b
WHERE client= @client
```

Comment: Thanks Feryal!  That's pretty close but it's selecting the oldest one for some reason.  I'll try and play with the code a little bit but this is definitely in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it:

```
$tsql = "SELECT distinct  main.serviceType, b.product, b.provider, b.rate, b.qty, b.updated
    FROM contracts AS main
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 
                serviceType, product, provider, rate, qty, updated 
                FROM contracts as sub
                WHERE main.serviceType = sub.serviceType AND client='{$_POST['client']}'
                ORDER BY ID DESC
                ) b

    WHERE client='{$_POST['client']}' ";
```

Thanks Feryal.  I just had to change the ORDER BY to ID since I made numerous changes during the same day.